# Does Postgres have a function for converting text into ASCII escaped or HTML escaped text?

Tags: type-conversion, format

Is there a builtin Postgres function that converts multi-line text into ASCII escaped or HTML escaped form and vice versa?

I need to store multi-line text as `name=value` pairs, basically line `.ini` files, where `Value` is the escaped text which should fit on a single line, but I prefer a format that doesn't use numeric codes to express the non-printing characters if such a format is available.

The multi-line text is not that short and could be upto 65K in length.

Postgres does something similar when it converts multi-line text as single lines in plain format backups without using SQL inserts.
It is the type of text passed to the `COPY tablename (column1, column2, columnxx)from stdin` when the plain text backup is viewed.

I have tried `quote_literal` but it didn't come out the way I want.

Is the function that does the conversion standalone?